# How to call an app helper method from an RSpec test in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The title is self explanatory.

Everything I've tried led to a "undefined method".

To clarify, I am not trying to test a helper method. I am trying to use a helper method in an integration test.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You just need to include the relevant helper module in your test to make the methods available:

```
describe "foo" do
  include ActionView::Helpers

  it "does something with a helper method" do
    # use any helper methods here
```

It's really as simple as that.

Comment: Can you tell how to call the method?
I have tried `SearchHelper::formatResultDate(r.date)` and `formatResultDate(r.date)` but get yet another "undefined method".
Thks

Comment: Is that your own helper? Is `SearchHelper` a module? If so, just replace `inlucde ActionView::Helpers` by `include SearchHelper`, and then you should just be able to call the method with `formatResultDate(r.date)`.

Comment: This didn't work for me when testing mailers. for example `expect(mail.body).to match(I18n.t('some.path', argument: link_to(value, custom_url_helper(value)))`.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone coming late to this question, it is answered on the [Relish](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec#spec-with-view-that-accesses-helper-method-helpers) site.

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "items/search.html.haml" do
  before do
    controller.singleton_class.class_eval do
      protected
      def current_user
        FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:merchant)
      end
      helper_method :current_user
    end
  end

  it "renders the not found message when @items is empty" do
    render

    expect(
      rendered
    ).to match("Sorry, we can't find any items matching &quot;&quot;.")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to use a helper method on your view test, you can go with the following:

```
before do
  view.extend MyHelper
end
```

It must be inside a `describe` block.

It works for me on rails 3.2 and rspec 2.13

Comment: If we assume you are in a spec/helpers/my_helper_spec.rb from where comes the "view" in the spec?

Comment: @IvailoBardarov Sorry, this is for using inside views. As the OP sais: `To clarify, I am not trying to test a helper method.`

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Thomas Riboulet's post on Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/dd08rq):

At the beginning of your spec file add this:

```
def helper
  Helper.instance
end

class Helper
  include Singleton
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
end
```

and then call a particular helper with `helper.name_of_the_helper`.

This particular example includes the [ActionView's NumberHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html). I needed the [UrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html), so I did `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` and `helper.link_to`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails , you should initialize the spec/ directory (where specs will reside) with:

```
$ rails generate rspec:install
```

this will generate an rails_helper.rb with the option

```
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
```

and finally require the new rails_helper in you helper_spec.rb instead of requiring 'spec_helper'.

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe ApplicationHelper do
  ...
end
```

good luck.

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you're trying to test the helper method. In order to do this you'll have to put your spec file into `spec/helpers/`. Given you're using the `rspec-rails` gem, this will provide you a `helper` method that allows you to call any helper method on it.

There's a nice example over in [the official `rspec-rails` documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-12-2/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec):

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe "#page_title" do
    it "returns the default title" do
      expect(helper.page_title).to eq("RSpec is your friend")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nop, there are plenty of answer about testing helper methods. I am trying to user a helper method in a integration test. Tks anyway

Comment: Oh okay. If you could expand your question and give a little more detail (maybe some code examples) I'll try to help you anyways :)